# Saving one big array in several smaller mallocs

Tags: c

Currently trying to implement a file-system in user-space using fuse. Although this is not important, it underlines why im forcing some restrictions on this problem.

Im trying to emulate a disk in memory, **I created several "blocks" (as a struct seen below), allocated by 1024 bytes.** 1024 of these "blocks" is a segment, my emulated disk is made of several of these segments.

Now I already implemented my filesystem, but im stuck on the issue that any file created that is bigger than the 1024bytes a single "block" can hold, is causing me some issues. What i want is to take something, lets say a big array (over 1024 bytes in size) and save it using two or more of these "blocks".

```
typedef struct block{
void *data;
} block
```

My current method of saving anything has been done using memcopy(), but I cannot figure out how to split a bigger data-set while doing this. Although im sure there is some simple method.

```
int someArray[2*1024]
memcpy(&blockPointer->data, &someArray, sizeof(someArray));
// Too big to fit! :/
```

Any help in this would be appreciated, while this is not as code-specific as it is me just not being able to figure out how to do it in the first place.

Comment: Use multiple `memcpy` calls?

Comment: Just use pointer arithmetic and multiple memcpy calls, one per block. The magic is knowing which blocks to use.

Comment: Ah so i simply use pointer arithmetic on the array to split it, makes good sense. How do I then set them back togeather when reading it?

Comment: You will, presumably, have an array of `block` structures, and you will have to split your writes across blocks with multiple calls to `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  You just have to keep tabs on how many blocks there are in the array of blocks so you don't go beyond the bounds of the simulated disk.

Comment: And be careful with your memcpy, no "&" if `blockPointer->data` is a pointer (and not a eg. a struct)